# selecting a div tag with jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Hi I have 2 divs both displaying dates and having the same name. I want to specifically display the first div for now, the second date for later on. I have tried searching but what I found is that you can specify the div name element and distinguish between both divs by it.

```
(This is the first date which I want to display)
<div class="home-weather-sub-div-bar">
<span class="datetext1">Sunday, March  3, 2013 updated 14:45:00 CET</span>
</div>

(This is the second date which I want to display)    
<div class="home-weather-sub-div-bar">
<span class="datetext1">Monday, March  4, 2013 until noon</span>
</div>
```

So to be clear, I have tried to select "div.home-weather-sub-div-bar" and "span.datetext1" yet it will still display Sunday, March 3, 2013 updated 14:45:00 CET Monday and then it will concatenate also March 4, 2013 until noon in the same line.

Any help please?

Comment: can u post your Jsoup code?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `div` tags with given attributes and then choose which one you want:

```
Document doc = ...

final Elements divs = doc.select("div.home-weather-sub-div-bar"); // Select the div-tags

Element firstDiv = divs.get(0); // get the first div
Element secondDiv = divs.get(1); // get the second div


System.out.println(firstDiv.text()); // print the text
System.out.println(secondDiv.text());
```

With the html you've posted i get this output:

```
Sunday, March 3, 2013 updated 14:45:00 CET
Monday, March 4, 2013 until noon
```